# Properties of matrix functions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis

Can I say that a certain matrix function is absolutely continuous or monotonically increasing in $\lambda$(assuming that the matrix is a function of $\lambda$)?

In other words, are these "properties" (absolutely continuous and monotonically increasing in $\lambda$) valid for matrices?

Comment: Absolute continuity one can presumably define by components. An often-used ordering on the matrices is that $A \geq B$ iff $A-B$ is positive semidefinite; whether this makes sense for your application depends on the details of your application and where your matrices come from. You should probably include more details in this question for it to get a good answer.

Comment: To make things clearer: I am trying to check if a certain quadratic form is maximized at the true value of /lambda.I cant take the derivative with respect to \lambda because it is a complicated function of \lambda. So, I was thinking of showing that 2x1 vectors increase in lambda and the inverse of the var-covar matrix increase in lambda. Thus conclude that the whole quadratic form increases in lambda. For that I wanted to check if the above properties are definied component wise for matrices and vectors or not? Thanks!

Comment: I just want to add one additional thing: That I can not write these matrices explicitly because they are very cumbersome and huge so I cant really know what each component of the vector or matrix is.